# Python - Count of day of month results group impacted by incorrect sort_values

Tags: python

I'm incrementally chipping away at a python script which I want to read in a csv file of payment dates to determine the payment cycles of the individual parties so that I can predict future payment dates.

My script intends to eventually provide:

- count the number of occurrences of the day of month
- count the number of occurrences of the week day
- combine the counts of both day of month and week day and produce a percentage sorted by highest at the top
- if day of month value was the greatest and Where the most used dates were not used in some dates, did the date used fall on a weekend (will also merge in public holidays to make it more accurate) if true then add that date to the highest count as well
- recalculate percentages using adjusted weightings

Now I've only just started so, here are my **issues**:

- I have manage to get the day from the date in my script. I have then applied a sort which does not work so, when it then goes to count the occurrences of the value, it is creating more than one group for the same value which should have been sorted
- I have added a day of week which isn't working at all - it seems to be referring to today rather than the date I'm asking it to look at when determining the day

*I'll work through the rest of the steps of my script intent much later, haven't discovered problems I haven't created yet*

**data and script**

I have a csv example with 10 rows representing 10 months of payments:

party, date, debit , credit

Netflix,22/01/2021,-$19.99 , $-
Netflix,22/02/2021,-$19.99 , $-
Netflix,22/03/2021,-$19.99 , $-
Netflix,22/04/2021,-$19.99 , $-
Netflix,24/05/2021,-$19.99 , $-
Netflix,22/06/2021,-$19.99 , $-
Netflix,22/07/2021,-$19.99 , $-
Netflix,23/08/2021,-$19.99 , $-
Netflix,22/09/2021,-$19.99 , $-
Netflix,22/10/2021,-$19.99 , $-

**python script**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import groupby

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\mattl\OneDrive\Desktop\example_netflix.csv")

# Convert to a Date format here
df['NewDate']=df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y'))

# Extract Month and store as new column
df['Month']=df['NewDate'].apply(lambda x: x.month)

# Extract Day and store as new column
df['Day']=df['NewDate'].apply(lambda x: x.day)

# Extract Day of week and store as new column
df['DayOfWeek']=df['NewDate'].apply(lambda x: datetime.today().weekday())

# Sort the data frame in descending dates
df.sort_values('Day')
print('CSV File rows')
print(df)

# Count the occurrences of the day in the set
st = [(key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(df['Day'])]

# Result of Count
print('Count Results')
print(st)
```

**results**

```
CSV File rows
party        date         debit   credit     NewDate  Month  Day  DayOfWeek
0  Netflix  22/01/2021  -$19.99     $-    2021-01-22      1   22          2
1  Netflix  22/02/2021  -$19.99     $-    2021-02-22      2   22          2
2  Netflix  22/03/2021  -$19.99     $-    2021-03-22      3   22          2
3  Netflix  22/04/2021  -$19.99     $-    2021-04-22      4   22          2
4  Netflix  24/05/2021  -$19.99     $-    2021-05-24      5   24          2
5  Netflix  22/06/2021  -$19.99     $-    2021-06-22      6   22          2
6  Netflix  22/07/2021  -$19.99     $-    2021-07-22      7   22          2
7  Netflix  23/08/2021  -$19.99     $-    2021-08-23      8   23          2
8  Netflix  22/09/2021  -$19.99     $-    2021-09-22      9   22          2
9  Netflix  22/10/2021  -$19.99     $-    2021-10-22     10   22          2
Count Results
[(22, 4), (24, 1), (22, 2), (23, 1), (22, 2)]
```

You're help explaining my existing problems are very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are always using TODAY'S weekday (`datetime.today().weekday()`).  You should be using `x.weekday()`.

Comment: you dont need all those apply's either

Comment: @TimRoberts I got it working with `df['WeekDay']=df['NewDate'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday())` thank you

Comment: @JoranBeasley I'm not sure how you'd format that without the apply

Comment: The group counting is still a problem, It would appear that, if I have to rely on a sort order, then having a count of day of week and day of month cannot be done together from the same data set. Is that right?

Comment: `df['Day'] = df['newDate'].dt.day`  or maybe just `df['Day'] = df['newDate'].day`

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks, that worked for all except `df['WeekDay']=df['NewDate'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday())` which appears to not support weekday